# How would I fix this date?

Tags: node.js, date, discord, discord.js

```
let time = args.shift();
let timeUnit = time.split('').pop();
if (timeUnit === 'd') timeUnit = 86400;
else if  (timeUnit === 'h') timeUnit = 3600;
else if (timeUnit === 'm') timeUnit = 60;
else {
    time.push(timeUnit);
    timeUnit = 1;
}
time *= timeUnit *= 1000;

var endingTime = new Date();
endingTime.setTime(endingTime.getTime() + time);
console.log(endingTime);

// When I type in _gcreate (the command) 1d it says the error:
// Invalid Date
// Even though I tell it to add milliseconds and whatnot.
```

I am creating a bot for giveaways on Discord.JS. It throws the error `Invalid Date`.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straightforward to debug.  If you use a step-through debugger, or simply go line by line on the console, you can see that your multiplication operation sets `time` to `NaN`, as you can't multiply a string like `"1d"` by a number like `86400`.

You'll need to separate out the `1` from the `"1d"` first.

(Also, it's fairly uncommon to see `*=` used twice on one line.  You probably meant just `*` for the second one.)

Answer (score 0):

So the reason `Date()` returns invalid is because `new Date()` is already a valid UNIX time. Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setTime) for reference. Try doing `Date().setTime(/*do stuff in here/*)` - but the reason it doesn't work is because `new Date()` is already a UNIx timestamp.

I also suggest you look at [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/docs/), it'd probably be easier to setup. `moment.set(timeGoesHere)` would be useful.